# Converting a list of strings to a list of variables

Tags: python

I am trying to convert a list of string to a list of variables

from :

```
listStrings = ['varA','varB','varC']
```

to:

```
listVar = [varA,varB,varC]
```

then I will use this listVar[] to call via

```
from otherfile import *
```

where otherfile.py have :

```
varA = "SELECT blabla"
varB = "SELECT foofoo"
varC = "SELECT lalala"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try using `getattr`:

In `foo.py`:

```
x = 1
y = 2
```

Then in other file:

```
import foo
names = ['x', 'y']
data = []
for n in names:
    data.append(getattr(foo, n))
data
#[1, 2]
```

Or you can use `globals()` (though this is not recommended because variable with the same name will be overridden if you use multiple `from xxx import *`):

```
from foo import *
names = ['x', 'y']
data = []
for n in names:
    data.append(globals()[n])
data
#[1, 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `globals()`:

```py
# otherfile.py
varA = "SELECT blabla"
varB = "SELECT foofoo"
varC = "SELECT lalala"
```

```py
# main file
from otherfile import *
listStrings = ['varA','varB','varC']
listVar = [globals()[k] for k in listStrings]
print(listVar)
```